# How to trouble shoot servlet output not appearing on browser, even though servlet otherwise working fine

Tags: google-app-engine, debugging, servlets

Log messages indicate that the servlet runs fine.  But when 
we click the button to fire that servlet, nothing shows up on the browser.

I am debugging this.  That is, I put debugging statements  in
the code.

out.println (" ** debugging message ** ")

.. more of the code ...

out.println (" ** debugging message two ")
return 0

... rest of the code ...

I get the two debugging messages.  When I remove the return 
zeros, allowing the rest of the code to execute,
none of the debugging messages show up.

When I stop the rest of the code from executing, I see
all the output on the browser that I should from the first
part of the program.

Without any debugging messages, in Network Mode, 
I see the GET and "Size" of 0.00 kb, a return code of 302
and a time of 152 seconds.  And the type is html.

This servlet used to work fine.

Comment: you need to debug it from the browser side

Comment: Have you tried debugging it locally in Eclipse, IntelliJ, etc?  Without any code this question is very broad.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your advice on this.   Using the technique that we described above, we identified the problem as some Transaction Processing code--but that problem is well beyond the scope of this thread!